# Canon custom white balance does not import to Lightroom / Photoshop

Tags: canon, lightroom, raw, white-balance

I have a Canon SL1.  I snapped several shots this morning with a custom white balance that was set in camera.  When I import the photos to Lightroom, they come in without the custom white balance.  The white balance in Lightroom is set to "as shot", but the white balance is not the custom white balance as shot.

I set the custom white balance from an image within the camera, and the image that it was set from was also imported.  I can't find how to set the white balance from that image in Lightroom.  The Photoshop Camera Raw plugin also renders the incorrect white balance.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  I really just need to use the in camera white balance.  The RAW thumbnails have the correct white balance in the file explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Camera Raw (which is used for raw conversion by both Photoshop and lightroom) and most other raw converter applications created by third parties (those other than the manufacturer of a specific camera) ignore the in camera settings for things such as white balance, contrast, saturation, etc. at the time the photo was taken. Instead, each application applies what their designers considered to be a good default starting point for a particular camera.

Canon's in-house products such as *Picture Style Editor* and *Digital Photo Professional* read the in camera settings and apply them at the time you first open an image taken with an EOS camera. You are free to change them as you wish, but it is nice to have the settings selected when the picture was taken as the starting point. The in-house applications provided by other camera manufacturers are similar. They usually provide the option to open the raw file using the in camera settings at the time the photo was taken.